# European turbo warrants

Tags: options, option-pricing, eurex

Totally new to the world of quant finance, so perhaps this is an odd question...

Does there exist an American equivalent to the German style "knock out zertifkate"?  (The name might be slightly wrong.)

Not even exactly sure what they are, but from what I did learn about their behavior, the nearest thing I could find on Wikipedia was:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbo_warrant

If there is *not* an american equivalent, does anybody know where to get English language details and pricing history/data?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

I haven't encountered them, but if you mean "***Hebel-Zertifikate***" as [defined on *Wikipedia*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zertifikat_%28Wirtschaft%29#Hebel-Zertifikate_.28auch%3a_Turbo-_oder_Knock-out-Zertifikate.2C_Mini-Futures.29) they just seem to be **leveraged certificates with an obligatory stop-loss knock-out**.

Those *turbo warrants* you mention are more or less the same as [**Mini Futures**](http://www.vam.ag/product-know-how/leveraged-certificates/mini-futures.html). Depending on issuer or some small differences, they can also come up as **Turbo / Short Certificates** (naming used by *The Royal Bank of Scotland*) or [**knock-out certificates**](http://en.wienerborse.at/prices_statistics/certificates/knockout/).

So you can encounter **many names for essentially similar/identical products**.

Your pricing question is a bit too vague. There are so many products that you would have to define what you're interested in (preferably what market/exchange). You can browse through the websites of the exchanges where products you're interested in are listed. For example [**Wiener Börse**](http://en.wienerborse.at/certificates/) has some pricing data for numerous certificates.